# Как создать ассоциативный массив из данных mysql с некой плюшкой

Tags: php, mysqli

подскажите как создать массив из данных mysql + с добавлением параметра null если количество данных из бд меньше чем указано.

Получаю данные вот так:

```
$lim = 6;
$user = array();
$sql = "select login from `$tb_user` where `id` limit $lim"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $user[] = $row;
}
```

На выходе получаю вот такой массив:

```
[{"login":"Admin"},{"nick":"Vera"},{"nick":"Roma"}]
```

Как сделать что бы на выходе было **6** пунктов данных в массиве только вот допустим у нас есть уже **3** которые выбрались из бд, и у нас есть лимит в **6** то к этим данным добавить 3 - null значения т.е. вот так:

```
[{"login":"Admin"},{"login":"Vera"},{"login":"Roma"},null,null,null]
```

Если допустим из бд мы получили только 1 значение то так:

```
[{"login":"Admin"},null,null,null,null,null]
```

Еще нужно что бы учитывалось что значение переменной **$lim** может меняться к примеру на **12** или **10**

Вот такой велосипед мне нужно сообразить. Подскажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если на стороне пхп, то

```
$user = array_pad($user, $lim, null);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное именно то что надо!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
( SELECT login FROM data_table )
UNION ALL
( SELECT NULL FROM some_table )
ORDER BY login IS NULL 
    /* , login */
LIMIT @rows_limit
```

где `some_table` - таблица, гарантированно содержащая записей не меньше, чем `@rows_limit`, либо CTE, генерирующее такое количество записей.

Comment: есть ли смысл тащить эту  логику на сторону БД ?

Comment: @teran Понятия не имею... но по тексту вопроса товарищ не желает "добивать" набор NULL-записями (вроде и всего делов-то), если количество записей в нём меньше требуемого, а напихать их в rowset на клиенте вряд ли получится - так что с озвученными ограничениями только на стороне сервера.